# Error while trying to add external local fonts in nextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, fonts

I'm trying to add local font to my NextJS + TailwindCSS project.
I have added the font inside public/fonts folder and I'm following the docs:

This is my code

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local'
const inter = Inter({
    subsets: ['latin'],
})

const recoleta = localFont({
    src: 'fonts/Recoleta-Regular.ttf',
    fontFamily: 'Recoleta',
})
```

And I'm getting this error from the terminal.

I need help on which folder to add it or how to configure it perfectly.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './fonts/Recoleta-Regular.ttf'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had this error and fixed the issue by setting it up as such. Used https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/font#src for assistance.
Using app folder.

page.tsx:

```
import CustomFont from '@next/font/local'

const cfont = CustomFont({
  src: '../public/fonts/cfont.ttf',
  variable: '--font-cfont',
})

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={`${cfont.variable}`}>
      <div className="font-cfont">
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        cfont: ['var(--font-cfont)', ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: why can't we use `/fonts/cfont.ttf` to reference the public folder like it tells us to in the docs for image?

Comment: Font need be inside `"/src/app/fonts"`

Comment: I noticed both way work, either in /app or /public folder, using relative paths. 
I prefer to stick with fonts placed in the public folder as it has always been a convention.